# Symfony form read only field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

How should I render `read-only` fields using Symfony form component?

This is how I am trying to do that to no avail:

**Symfony 2**

```
$builder
    ->add('descripcion', 'text', array(
        'read_only' =>'true'
    ));
}
```

**Symfony 3**

```
$builder
    ->add('descripcion', TextType::class, array(
        'read_only' => 'true'
    ));
}
```

Comment: if an answer is solution to solve this problem, please mark as accepted :)

Comment: if you found this question looking for Symfony Forms support for readonly data classes - as of 2023/06 it's not possible - closest thing one can get to is defining custom mapper implementing DataMapperInterface and $builder->setDataMapper, but note "The data passed to the mapper is not yet validated"

Answer (score 39):

Provided answers all end up with this exception on **Symfony 3**:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: "The option "read_only" does not exist.

The right way to do this is to take advantage of `attr` property on the field:

```
->add('descripcion', TextareaType::class, array(
    'attr' => array(
        'readonly' => true,
    ),
));
```

If you are after way to have a field with data not posted to the server during form submission, you should use `disabled` like:

```
->add('field', TextareaType::class, array(
    'disabled' => true,
));
```

on your form builder object.

Comment: Downvote because this method will set the HTML attribute, but the Form will still accept a new value for `descripcion` if the request includes it. So it gives authors a false sense of security.

Comment: Thanks for your downvote, but **ReadOnly**, a client side feature to annotate an html form field is not a `security` thing. You must handle you `security` at server side. If you have problem with Symfony, you may go to their Github account and submit an issue there.

Comment: @Trix I think user2045006 meant that with your solution, any user can change manually the attribute in the html and post the field, and the form will automatically update the entity. Using the readonly option of the form will make sure the entity is not updated even if the user change the html, so it's more secure.

Comment: this HTML form behaviour is by design. User should be able to change anything, client side. You can AUDIT and CONTROL everything, server side. This is called web.

Comment: @Pmpr Symfony provides by design a way to make a field read-only by both disabling field edition at client side and adding a security guard at server side. Check [disabled option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#disabled). Although OP only asked how to _render_ a read-only field, he/she most probably meant how to handle read-only fields on both sides. That's why I agree with Courtney Miles advising against using only readonly HTML attribute.

Comment: @fbastien thanks but the `disabled` has nothing to do with Symfony. That's an [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) which disables the control for the output. Also there is another html attribute called `readonly` which [prohibits changes to the control](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2), but all this is client side.

Comment: @Pmpr Thanks for updating your (most upvoted) answer. I know about `disabled` and `readonly` HTML specs, but the OP was asking how to do it using Symfony Form component, not writing plain HTML. Moreover, in most use cases, rendering a `disabled` or `readonly` field is the reflection that this field value shouldn't be altered on server side as well. Symfony's `disabled` option makes both client and server sides consistent regarding immutability. BTW data not being posted to the server is HTML spec, Symfony option is rather about ignoring field server-side even if a malicious client sends data.

Answer (score 18):

I believe the only secure method to present a form field as readonly and also  prevent your form from accepting a new value in a request is the following.

```
$builder->add(
    'description',
    TextType::class,
    ['disabled' => true]
);
```

The other suggestion of using either `['attr' => ['readonly' => true]]` or `['attr' => ['disabled' => true]]` will leave you vulnerable to forged requests.

Both the latter options will set either `readonly` or `disabled` attributes on the field, but your Form will still accept a new value for this field if included in the request.

Only the first option above will both disable the form field and also prevent your Form from accepting a new value for the field in the request.

I have tested this with Symfony Form 3.4. I do not know if 4 behaves the same.

Comment: Yes, Symfony 4 behaves the same.

Comment: Good answer. With Symfony 5 works, too.

Answer (score 9):

You have declared your read only attribute to a string, it needs to be a boolean.

**remove the quotes around `true`**

like this:

```
->add('descripcion','text',array('read_only' => true))
```

true, without the quotes.

Answer (score 8):

Symfony 4 allows using only "disabled" option in form field. But it is something different that "readonly".

- Disabled - user can't edit field and its value IS NOT passed during form submision.
- Readonly - user can't edit field but its value IS passed during form submision.

Only solution I found for "readonly" is:

```
->add('fieldname', TextType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'attr'=> [ 'readonly' => true ]
        ])
```

Comment: "Readonly - user can't edit field but its value IS passed during form submision.": Misleading, the user can edit the field by modifying the HTML, POSTing the form by other means (JS, Postman...) and so on. `readonly` is only client-side, just like `required` (that's why `required` fields should always have `NotBlank` validation server-side).

Answer (score 6):

*read_only* is deprecated since Symfony 2.8. So please use *readonly* instead. And provide boolean value for this attribute

```
->add('','text',array('readonly' => true))
```

Answer (score 4):

Update: since Symfony 3.0, the *readonly* value should be set in the *attr* option. 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/form.html#read-only

The *disabled* option can also be used instead.

Comment: "disabled" and "readonly" are NOT the same thing and can not be used interchangeably!!!

While they both render in similar way to the user, a readonly field will be part of the post, while a disabled field will not.

Comment: @Olia.BN "a readonly field will be part of the post" which is usually not what you are trying to achieve when disallowing a user from modifying a field. See my other comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158707/symfony-form-read-only-field/49899877#comment132405539_55453100)

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` and not `read_only`. You shoud make this option in `attr` like this:

```
->add('', TextType::class, array('attr'=> array('readonly' => true)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using the disabled option because any submitted value will be ignored as per the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#disabled

```
$builder->add('descripcion', TextType::class, [
    'disabled' => 'true',
]);
```

Comment: There's a major difference between: "yes, I want this field but its value must not change" and "i don't want this field"

Comment: @emix Yes, and `readonly` will ensure neither: The user can still modify the field by POSTing any value he wants, by editing the HTML to remove the attribute, by adding a `value` attribute, etc. If you are using `readonly` as "yes, I want this field but its value must not change" you are introducing a vulnerability in your app. Instead you should use `disabled` as PJately stated and retrieve the value server-side (if it cannot change it means you already have it, so relying on the client to give it to you again is unnecessary and foolish).

Answer (score -1):

Let me add something that the other answers didn't help to manage with. The treatment as field but "tweak" to disable edition may work in many cases. However, it's at least difficult to render in some formats that fully prevent edition (i.e., render as a label).

How to solve this? What I did is to define the field as HiddenType, and in the template, render using `{{ form.vars.value.myfield }}` or `{{ item.myfield }}` taking "item" as the entity object, enclosed in whatever you can think of, as any other HTML element.

Answer (score -1):

Other solution could be:

```
->add('value', TextType::class, ['disabled' => true]):
```

Taken from: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#disabled

Answer (score -2):

Only 'disabled' option does not cause an error

```
$builder
    ->add('descripcion', TextType::class, array(
        'disabled' => 'true'
    ));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If familia and proveedor are relations to other entity i think they shouldn't be text type. Try nullify their types or change to *entity* type and check if it worked.